# Environment setting & development tools for my SharePoint 2013 project

Tags: sharepoint, iis

I want to start my first SharePoint project to build internal and external systems:-

So I am preparing to get the following to set the development environment and to publish live SharePoint applications:-

1. SharePoint Server 2013 Standard edition. As for now we do no need
   the enterprise features such as e-discover, BI, branding, etc.
2. Windows server 2012 & IIS as the operating system and hosting server respectively.
3. SQL server 2012 or 2008 for the database
4. Visual studio professional 2012 to develop web parts and use SharePoint templates.
5. Team foundation server 2012 to provides versioning control, bug tracing, etc.

So can anyone advice if I am missing any tools or software that are needed to develop and implement live internet & intranet SharePoint applications.

Second question should I use office 365 in my case?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's sufficient enough to start developing SharePoint applications. You may need SharePoint Designer 2013. You can also find the best-to-have hardware requirements for SharePoint development environment in my blog post (http://keremozen.com/2012/12/28/hardware-requirements-for-sharepoint-2013-development/).

Office 365 or on-prem installation choice totally depends on your needs.
Office 365 installation provides easy set-up, maintainability, scalebility and security. Your sites will be accessible 24x7. If you want full control on your sites you can prefer on-prem installation.

Regards